# JQueryMobile: When data-role="page" 's JS generated content is created/remove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Given a **one-html**-multiple-pages app, in each of my pages I plan JS inject long html codes and animations which can be heavy. HTML code such :

```
<div data-role="page" id="page11">
  ...
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page12">
 <h2 id="anchor12">Title: Page 12</h2>
 <script>myScript12() // inject complex content to #anchor12</script>
</div>
```

**1. When does my `myScript12()` is fired ? (When I open the .html file or when I click and open the #page12 ?**

**2. What happen to the JS generated content when I leave #page12 for an other page ?**

---

**Edit:** I don't want to load all my 20 heavy pages on .html load.

---

**Solution:** +1 for the [detailed explanation by Gajotres (JQM: document ready vs page events)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600), below is my current solution. To run the js ONLY when the given data-role="page" is displayed...

**Use the following JQM HTML/JS:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page12">
 <h2 id="anchor12">Title: Page 12</h2>
 <script>
$('#page12').on('pageinit') { //only run when page is displayed
     myScript12() // inject complex content to #anchor12
});</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That script will execute as soon as page is loaded into the **`DOM`**. That's why page events exist. Basically if you want to time your code execution do it inside a page event. If you want to find more about page event's read my other answer: **[jQuery Mobile: document ready vs page events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.
2. When you leave your page that content is still there loaded into the **`DOM`**. If you want to prevent large **`DOM`** content you can use [pagehide](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagehide/) event to clean previous page content. There's also an attribute that can be placed inside a data-role="page" div to prevent **`DOM`** cashing. Attribute name is **`data-dom-cache="true"`** and you can find more abut it [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html).

Comment: Generally speaking : I love your answers @___@